# repository does not have release file

Tags: antix

I get this error while doing `sudo apt update`

```
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/war1025/Debian_11  
Release' does not have a Release file
```

Comment: Ign:11 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/war1025/Debian_11  InRelease
Err:12 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/war1025/Debian_11  Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 195.135.223.226 80]

Answer (score 3):

The answer from web page is:
**Resource is no longer available!**
User home for `war1025` do not exist anymore. Find other place where the files are distributed.